# How to convert this VB code to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

```
Private mintDCLink As Integer = 0
Public Property DCLink() As Integer
    Get
        Return mintDCLink
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        mintDCLink = Value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Private mintDCLink As Integer = 0
    Public Property DCLink() As Integer
        Get
            Return mintDCLink
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            mintDCLink = Value
        End Set
    End Property

Comment: `public int DCLink {set;get;}`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert small parts of code from VB to C#, and you don't know the last one - best way is to use online code converters like [this](http://converter.telerik.com/).

About your code - here is it. Hope it helps.

```
int mintDCLink = 0;
public int DCLink {
    get {
        return mintDCLink;
    }
    set {
        mintDCLink = value;
    }
}
```

Or if you want code refactoring, here is shorter version of your code:

```
public int DCLink {get; set;}
```

Comment: public int DCLink { get; set; } is much simpler.

Comment: I know. But TS didn't ask for refactoring. He asked for converting.

Answer (score 2):

```
private int mintDCLink = 0;
public int DCLink {
    get { return mintDCLink; }
    set { mintDCLink = value; }
}
```